# How to save Worksheet to CSV from Excel in specific locale?

Tags: excel, csv, locale, vba

I work with an `.xlsx` Workbook and eventually output one of the `Worksheet`s to `csv`. The csv is to be used on a Citrix system with a different locale to my local computer. As such I would like to save the `csv`, on my local computer but in the locale native the the Citrix system (the file is consumed by a different application that expects native locale and doesn't have a setting to change).

For the sake of example, use the example where my local computer is `English - United Kingdom, 0809` and the Citrix system is `English - United States, 0409`.

Is there a way to force Excel to save a CSV with a specific locale either through file settings or VBA?

```
Sub SaveInCitrixLocale()

    Dim filenom As String
    filenom = "myfile"
    ActiveWorksheet.SaveAs filenom, "csv", , , , , , , , True
    'The last argument os SaveAs is called "Local" but only accepts TRUE/FALSE - see msdn link

End Sub
```

The msdn page suggests that the [Applicaion.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185(v=office.15).aspx) method doesn't offer the ability to save in a arbitrary locale.